# CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type warning for Interlocked.Exchange(ref c, null)

Tags: c#, interlocked, nullable-reference-types, .net-5

The following code works properly in .NET core 3.1, but generates wrongly the warning *CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type*:

```
#nullable enable
using System.Threading;

namespace InterlockedExchangeNullProblem {
  public class Class1 {
    public Class1() {
      object? o = new object();
      var o1 = Interlocked.Exchange(ref o, null); // ok
      class2? c = new class2();
      var c1 = Interlocked.Exchange(ref c, null); // error CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
    }
  }
  public class class2{}
}
```

If it works for `object?`, it should also work for `class2?`.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
var c2 = Interlocked.Exchange<class2?>(ref c, null);
```

Note: The compiler made c1 of type `class2` instead `class2?`.

If you agree that this needs to be corrected, then please upvote:

[developercommunity.visualstudio.com: Interlocked.Exchange: compiler choses wrong Exchange with nullable types](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1259784/interlockedexchange-compiler-choses-wrong-exchange.html)